# Missing typeface when activating wordpress Divi child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, typeface

after creating a child theme that is functioning correctly, I have a problem with the typeface modules.ttf font-family : ETmodules
The typeface works correctly if I don't use the child theme and it is not considered missing when I verify in development tools. You can see the problem in the header on this page before the telephone number: https://preprod03.groupepointsrezo.fr/
I tried adding the typeface to the child them using the same folder hierarchy.
I have also added this to my child theme style.css file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: ETmodules;
src: url(core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf);
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: did you add the core folder to your child theme? because the relative path points to this.

Comment: though if the font is registered in the parent themes css, there should be no reason to register the font face again

Comment: @Stender you are right, I should not need to add the font face and I should not need to add the core folder but I did just because it is not working. My other typeface is working correctly

Comment: But your font is working fine..

Comment: Is it because the icons should be a phone?

Comment: Do you know if I must enqueue custom stylesheets if they are in the child theme folder?

Comment: Because if so... it is because you are missing an ` \ ` in the `content`..

Comment: like... `content: 'e090';` should be `content: '\e090';` - then it is a phone

Comment: Yes, the one on the top right should be a phone

Comment: in your css `.btn-tel a::before` change the content to `content: '\e090';` and it is a phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stender answer is correct. I am missing the backslash in the style content

```
content: "\e090";
```

Thank you. I don't know how to attribute the answer to you because you answered with a comment